# Npm package sails hook debug with Webstorm

Tags: debugging, npm, sails.js

So... 
I got this npm package I'm developing for the sails framework.
The NPM package is:

https://github.com/stuk88/ecobill-hook-cms

Its loaded as a hook in sails.
what is the best way to debug the package with breakpoints inside Webstorm?

Comment: Can you elaborate the "debug" part? .. debug in terms of logging? or in terms of "breakpoints" ?

Comment: Using breakpoint inside Webstorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
So the answer to that is to git clone the hook project to some other folder, and then link that folder to a folder insides /api/hooks/%hook_name%

To make a link in Windows 10, use this command (In Admin CMD):

`mklink /d c:\target c:\source`

(Not shure about the attributes order, check it out in --help)

Then the debugging will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Go to Run>Edit configurations
2. Click on (+) and pick Node.js

   1. Select one node interpreter in case is emtpy
   2. set your working directory
   3. Javascript file must be `app.js` in the same working directory
   4. application parameters (I usually set `--dev`)
   5. Environment Variables (whatever you want there)
3. Save (Ok button)
4. Set some breakpoints within your modules
5. In the left top corner, just pick your configuration and click on the Debug icon.

That's all. It works for me.

Webstorm: 2016.3.1

Comment: and how do I remove the node_modules from the excluded folders?

Comment: Go to settings/preferences and in that menu browse to the category Directories. Pick on node-modules and be sure is not red.

Comment: Cant unselect it.

Comment: I think it works anyway. Have you tried to debug in any module?

Comment: @StasArshanski Ok, there is another way, I updated my answer

Comment: Sorry. not helpful to me. The breakpoints within node_modules are not firing at all.